# How to achieve that input Logout doesn't look like button?

Tags: html, css, forms

How to achieve that input Logout doesn't look like button ? Can I change that to div but to hold functionality to send POST

It looks like

[image]

and need to looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add the below style attribute to you button html.

```
style="color:#0077CC; border:1px solid #000000; background:#000000;"
```

Answer (score 1):

two ways to do it,

- write JS and bind it to a logout href, this JS wil post vars to your logout page
- Style the logout button as suggested by @jagadeesan, but with no border, like this `style="color:#0077CC; border:none; background:#000000;"`